# Passing a two dimensional array to a function

Tags: c, arrays, function, matrix

Is there a way to pass a two dimensional array to a function that the size is defined by an input like the following:

```
scanf("%d",&n);
matrix[n][n];
```

?

I don't want to use a define for the second parameter of the function.

Comment: If you show us the function declaration then it would be easy for us to tell you how to pass the 2D array to your function.

Answer (score 1):

In C 1999 implementations and in C 2011 implementations that support variable-length arrays, you can pass an array with a run-time dimension by declaring the function this way:

```
ReturnType foo(size_t n, ElementType matrix[][n]) …
```

In the calling code, after having obtained `n`, you can define the matrix with:

```
ElementType matrix[n][n];
```

and you can call the function with:

```
foo(n, matrix)
```

Notes:

- `ReturnType` and `ElementType` are placeholders for types you choose. `ReturnType` may be `void`.
- To get the definition of `size_t`, you should `#include <stddef.h>`.
- You should define only small arrays this way. Most C implementations provide only a limited amount of space for variable-length arrays with automatic storage duration, and you will overflow the stack if the array is too large.
- If you are using GCC to compile, you can request C 1999 or C 2011 with `-std=c99` or `-std=c11`. See the [GCC documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/) for additional options.

If the array is large, you can define it this way instead:

```
ElementType (*matrix)[n] = malloc(n * sizeof *matrix);
if (!matrix)
    Handle error.
```

And later you must free it with:

```
free(matrix);
```

If your C implementation does not support variable-length arrays, then you can allocate space for `n*n` elements instead and index the array manually (an element at row `i` and column `j` would be at position `i*n+j`), possibly by writing some auxiliary functions to help with the indexing. In this case, you would pass the array to a function as a simple pointer to the element type, rather than a pointer to an array of elements.

Answer (score 0):

Use [variable length array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) feature of C99. Then pass it to your function as per the argument of the function with its size.

Comment: My suspicion: yet another candidate who doesn't know that one can pass VLAs to a function, and consequently downvotes any (correct) answer that asserts that it's possible... >.<

Comment: @H2CO3; :(((. Agreed.

Comment: Meanwhile, the question (which doesn't show research effort, and is trivial and lazy) has been upvoted. Gotta love the system.

Comment: @H2CO3; I did't upvoted! Trust me.

Comment: I know you would never do that, I was only trying to emphasize the weirdness of all this...

Comment: I am used to of this now :)

Comment: i did a little bit of research

Comment: What you were going to tell me? I am waiting for your reply....